How to make Caddy server keep the same subpath even if web app redirects to root path?
I have basic setup:

Caddy server
Some SPA web app

A static website is hosted under /subpath/spa, but it keeps navigating to a /page without subpath part. How to keep teh web app it served under /subpath/spa and /subpath/page in any condition?

 Some additional details that do not affect the main question: I actually prefer Caddy using this project and SPA web app is X-UI dashboard, all under Docker. But that does not really affect the question, I can remap your configs to Docker labels.

